# What is MOV CX,(DEVRD SHL 8) OR DRDWRHL doing in this device driver? Why put two interrupt types into the count register?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, device-driver

I want to mention that here in my code DEVRD = 0000 0100 (i.e. decimal 4 or interrupt 04h which is for overflow) and DRDWRHL = 0001 0110 (i.e. decimal 22 or interrupt 16h which is for keyboard input). here i am confused that why we will we put here (0000 0100 SHL 8) in CH and (0001 0110) in CL. what is it means that we are trying to put two interrupt types (04h for overflow and 16h for keyboard input) into counter register CX. what is counter register CX is doing here.

i am being more specific by mention that: here DEVRD stands for device read and DRDWTHL is stands for device read write header size. thanks in advance.

```
;
; Device call routines for MSDOS
;

INCLUDE DOSSEG.ASM

IFNDEF  KANJI
KANJI   EQU     0       ;FALSE
ENDIF

CODE    SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC  'CODE'
    ASSUME  SS:DOSGROUP,CS:DOSGROUP

.xlist
.xcref
INCLUDE DOSSYM.ASM
INCLUDE DEVSYM.ASM
.cref
.list

TITLE   DEV - Device call routines
NAME    Dev

    i_need  IOXAD,DWORD
    i_need  IOSCNT,WORD
    i_need  DEVIOBUF,4
    i_need  IOCALL,BYTE
    i_need  IOMED,BYTE
    i_need  IORCHR,BYTE
    i_need  CALLSCNT,WORD
    i_need  DMAAdd,DWORD
    i_need  NullDevPt,DWORD
    i_need  CallDevAd,DWORD
    i_need  Attrib,BYTE
    i_need  NULDEV,DWORD
    i_need  Name1,BYTE
    i_need  DevPt,DWORD
    i_need  DPBHead,DWORD
    i_need  NumIO,BYTE
    i_need  ThisDPB,DWORD
    i_need  DevCall,DWORD
    i_need  VerFlg,BYTE

SUBTTL IOFUNC -- DO FUNCTION 1-12 I/O
PAGE
IOFUNC_RETRY:
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING
    invoke  restore_world

    procedure   IOFUNC,NEAR
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING

; Inputs:
;       DS:SI Points to FCB
;       AH is function code
;               = 0 Input
;               = 1 Input Status
;               = 2 Output
;               = 3 Output Status
;               = 4 Flush
;       AL = character if output
; Function:
;       Perform indicated I/O to device or file
; Outputs:
;       AL is character if input
;       If a status call
;               zero set if not ready
;               zero reset if ready (character in AL for input. 
status)
; For regular files:
;       Input Status
;               Gets character but restores fcb_RR field
;               Zero set on EOF
;       Input
;               Gets character advances fcb_RR field
;               Returns ^Z on EOF
;       Output Status
;               Always ready
; AX altered, all other registers preserved

    MOV     WORD PTR [IOXAD+2],SS
    MOV     WORD PTR [IOXAD],OFFSET. 
DOSGROUP:DEVIOBUF
    MOV     WORD PTR [IOSCNT],1
    MOV     WORD PTR [DEVIOBUF],AX

IOFUNC2:
    TEST    [SI.fcb_DEVID],080H
    JNZ     IOTODEV
    JMP     IOTOFILE

IOTODEV:
    invoke  save_world
    PUSH    DS
    PUSH    SS
    POP     ES
    PUSH    SS
    POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP
    XOR     BX,BX
    MOV     [IOCALL.REQSTAT],BX
    MOV     BYTE PTR [IOMED],BL

    MOV     BX,OFFSET DOSGROUP:IOCALL

    MOV     CX,(DEVRD SHL 8) OR DRDWRHL   // I am in trouble here.
    OR      AH,AH
    JZ      DCALLR
    MOV     CX,(DEVRDND SHL 8) OR DRDNDHL
    DEC     AH
    JZ      DCALLR
    MOV     CX,(DEVWRT SHL 8) OR DRDWRHL
    DEC     AH
    JZ      DCALLO
    MOV     CX,(DEVOST SHL 8) OR DSTATHL
    DEC     AH
    JZ      DCALLO
DFLUSH:
    MOV     CX,(DEVIFL SHL 8) OR DFLSHL
DCALLR:
    MOV     AH,86H
DCALL:
    MOV     [IOCALL.REQLEN],CL
    MOV     [IOCALL.REQFUNC],CH
    MOV     CL,AH
    POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    CALL    DEVIOCALL
    MOV     DI,[IOCALL.REQSTAT]
    TEST    DI,STERR
    JZ      OKDEVIO
    MOV     AH,CL
    invoke  CHARHARD
    CMP     AL,1
    JZ      IOFUNC_RETRY
;Know user must have wanted ignore. Make sure device. 
shows ready so
;that DOS doesn't get caught in a status loop when user. 
simply wants
;to ignore the error.
    AND     BYTE PTR [IOCALL.REQSTAT+1], NOT (STBUI. 
SHR 8)
OKDEVIO:
    PUSH    SS
    POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP
    CMP     CH,DEVRDND
    JNZ     DNODRD
    MOV     AL,BYTE PTR [IORCHR]
    MOV     [DEVIOBUF],AL

DNODRD: MOV     AH,BYTE PTR [IOCALL.REQSTAT+1]
    NOT     AH                      ; Zero = busy, not zero = ready
    AND     AH,STBUI SHR 8

    invoke  restore_world
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    MOV     AX,WORD PTR [DEVIOBUF]
    return

DCALLO:
    MOV     AH,87H
    JMP     SHORT DCALL

IOTOFILE:
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    OR      AH,AH
    JZ      IOIN
    DEC     AH
    JZ      IOIST
    DEC     AH
    JZ      IOUT
    return                  ; NON ZERO FLAG FOR OUTPUT. 
STATUS

IOIST:
    PUSH    WORD PTR [SI.fcb_RR]        ; Save position
    PUSH    WORD PTR [SI.fcb_RR+2]
    CALL    IOIN
    POP     WORD PTR [SI.fcb_RR+2]      ; Restore position
    POP     WORD PTR [SI.fcb_RR]
    return

IOUT:
    CALL    SETXADDR
    invoke  STORE
    invoke  FINNOSAV
    CALL    RESTXADDR       ; If you change this into a jmp. 
don't come
    return                  ; crying to me when things don't work 
ARR

IOIN:
    CALL    SETXADDR
    invoke  LOAD
    PUSH    CX
    invoke  FINNOSAV
    POP     CX
    OR      CX,CX           ; Check EOF
    CALL    RESTXADDR
    MOV     AL,[DEVIOBUF]   ; Get byte from trans addr
    retnz
    MOV     AL,1AH          ; ^Z if EOF
    return

SETXADDR:
    POP     WORD PTR [CALLSCNT]     ; Return address
    invoke  save_world
    PUSH    WORD PTR [DMAADD]       ; Save Disk trans.   
addr
    PUSH    WORD PTR [DMAADD+2]
    PUSH    DS
    PUSH    SS
    POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP
    MOV     CX,WORD PTR [IOXAD+2]
    MOV     WORD PTR [DMAADD+2],CX
    MOV     CX,WORD PTR [IOXAD]
    MOV     WORD PTR [DMAADD],CX    ; Set byte trans. 
addr
    MOV     CX,[IOSCNT]             ; ioscnt specifies length of 
buffer
    POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    MOV     [SI.fcb_RECSIZ],1           ; One byte per record
    MOV     DX,SI                   ; FCB to DS:DX
    invoke  GETRRPOS
    JMP     SHORT RESTRET           ; RETURN ADDRESS

RESTXADDR:
    POP     WORD PTR [CALLSCNT]     ; Return address
    POP     WORD PTR [DMAADD+2]     ; Restore Disk trans 
addr
    POP     WORD PTR [DMAADD]
    invoke  restore_world
RESTRET:JMP     WORD PTR [CALLSCNT]      ; Return 
address
IOFUNC  ENDP

SUBTTL DEVIOCALL, DEVIOCALL2 - CALL A DEVICE
PAGE
    procedure   DEVIOCALL,NEAR
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING

; Inputs:
;       DS:SI Points to device FCB
;       ES:BX Points to request data
; Function:
;       Call the device
; Outputs:
;       None
; DS:SI,AX destroyed, others preserved

    LDS     SI,DWORD PTR [SI.fcb_FIRCLUS]

   entry   DEVIOCALL2
; As above only DS:SI points to device header on entry, 
and DS:SI is preserved
    MOV     AX,[SI.SDEVSTRAT]
    MOV     WORD PTR [CALLDEVAD],AX
    MOV     WORD PTR [CALLDEVAD+2],DS
    CALL    DWORD PTR [CALLDEVAD]
    MOV     AX,[SI.SDEVINT]
    MOV     WORD PTR [CALLDEVAD],AX
    CALL    DWORD PTR [CALLDEVAD]
    return
DEVIOCALL   ENDP

SUBTTL DEVNAME - LOOK FOR NAME OF DEVICE
PAGE
    procedure   DEVNAME,NEAR
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP,ES:DOSGROUP

; Inputs:
;       DS,ES:DOSGROUP
;       Filename in NAME1
; Function:
;       Determine if file is in list of I/O drivers
; Outputs:
;       Carry set if name not found
;       ELSE
;       Zero flag set
;       BH = Bit 7,6 = 1, bit 5 = 0 (cooked mode)
;            bits 0-4 set from low byte of attribute word
;       DEVPT = DWORD pointer to Device header of device
; Registers BX destroyed

    PUSH    SI
    PUSH    DI
    PUSH    CX

    IF      KANJI
    PUSH    WORD PTR [NAME1]
    CMP     [NAME1],5
    JNZ     NOKTR
    MOV     [NAME1],0E5H
NOKTR:
    ENDIF

    TEST    BYTE PTR [ATTRIB],attr_volume_id ; If looking 
for VOL id don't find devs
    JNZ     RET31
    MOV     SI,OFFSET DOSGROUP:NULDEV
LOOKIO:
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    TEST    [SI.SDEVATT],DEVTYP
    JZ      SKIPDEV                 ; Skip block devices
    PUSH    SI
    ADD     SI,SDEVNAME
    MOV     DI,OFFSET DOSGROUP:NAME1
    MOV     CX,4                    ; All devices are 8 letters
    REPE    CMPSW                   ; Check for name in list
    POP     SI
    JZ      IOCHK                   ; Found it?
SKIPDEV:
    LDS     SI,DWORD PTR [SI]       ; Get address of next 
device
    CMP     SI,-1                   ; At end of list?
    JNZ     LOOKIO
RET31:  STC                             ; Not found
RETNV:  PUSH    SS
    POP     DS
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP

    IF      KANJI
    POP     WORD PTR [NAME1]
    ENDIF

    POP     CX
    POP     DI
    POP     SI
    RET

IOCHK:
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING
    MOV     WORD PTR [DEVPT+2],DS         ; Save pointer to 
device
    MOV     BH,BYTE PTR [SI.SDEVATT]
    OR      BH,0C0H
    AND     BH,NOT 020H             ;Clears Carry
    MOV     WORD PTR [DEVPT],SI
    JMP     RETNV
DevName ENDP

    procedure   GetBP,NEAR
ASSUME  DS:DOSGROUP,ES:NOTHING

; Inputs:
;       AL = Logical unit number (A = 0)
; Function:
;       Find Drive Parameter Block
; Outputs:
;       ES:BP points to DPB
;       [THISDPB] = ES:BP
;       Carry set if unit number bad
; No other registers altered

    LES     BP,[DPBHEAD]    ; Just in case drive isn't valid
    AND     AL,3FH          ; Mask out dirty and device bits
    CMP     AL,BYTE PTR [NUMIO]
    CMC
    JC      GOTDPB          ; Get drive A
FNDDPB:
    CMP     AL,ES:[BP.dpb_drive]
    JZ      GOTDPB          ; Carry is clear if jump executed
    LES     BP,ES:[BP.dpb_next_dpb]
    JMP     SHORT FNDDPB
GOTDPB:
    MOV     WORD PTR [THISDPB],BP
    MOV     WORD PTR [THISDPB+2],ES
    RET
GetBP   ENDP

SUBTTL SETREAD, SETWRITE -- SET UP HEADER BLOCK
PAGE
    procedure   SETREAD,NEAR
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING

; Inputs:
;       DS:BX = Transfer Address
;       CX = Record Count
;       DX = Starting Record
;       AH = Media Byte
;       AL = Unit Code
; Function:
;       Set up the device call header at DEVCALL
; Output:
;       ES:BX Points to DEVCALL
; No other registers effected

    PUSH    DI
    PUSH    CX
    PUSH    AX
    MOV     CL,DEVRD
SETCALLHEAD:
    MOV     AL,DRDWRHL
    PUSH    SS
    POP     ES
    MOV     DI,OFFSET DOSGROUP:DEVCALL
    STOSB                   ; length
    POP     AX
    STOSB                   ; Unit
    PUSH    AX
    MOV     AL,CL
    STOSB                   ; Command code
    XOR     AX,AX
    STOSW                   ; Status
    ADD     DI,8            ; Skip link fields
    POP     AX
    XCHG    AH,AL
    STOSB                   ; Media byte
    XCHG    AL,AH
    PUSH    AX
    MOV     AX,BX
    STOSW
    MOV     AX,DS
    STOSW                   ; Transfer addr
    POP     CX              ; Real AX
    POP     AX              ; Real CX
    STOSW                   ; Count
    XCHG    AX,DX           ; AX=Real DX, DX=real CX, CX=real AX
    STOSW                   ; Start
    XCHG    AX,CX
    XCHG    DX,CX
    POP     DI
    MOV     BX,OFFSET DOSGROUP:DEVCALL
    RET

    entry   SETWRITE
ASSUME  DS:NOTHING,ES:NOTHING

; Inputs:
;       DS:BX = Transfer Address
;       CX = Record Count
;       DX = Starting Record
;       AH = Media Byte
;       AL = Unit Code
; Function:
;       Set up the device call header at DEVCALL
; Output:
;       ES:BX Points to DEVCALL
; No other registers effected

    PUSH    DI
    PUSH    CX
    PUSH    AX
    MOV     CL,DEVWRT
    ADD     CL,[VERFLG]
    JMP     SHORT SETCALLHEAD
SETREAD ENDP

do_ext

CODE    ENDS
END
```

Comment: dear tommylee I impressed by your reply. it is up to the point. but I want to mention that here in my code DEVRD = 0000 0100 
(i.e. decimal 4 or interrupt 04h which is for overflow) and DRDWRHL = 0001 0110 (i.e. decimal 22 or interrupt 16h which is for keyboard input).
 here i am confused that why we will we put here (0000 0100 SHL 8) in CH and (0001 0110) in CL. 
what is it means that we are trying to put two interrupt types (04h for overflow and 16h for keyboard input) into counter register CX.
 what is counter register CX is doing here.

Comment: i am being more specific by mention that: here DEVRD stands for device read and DRDWTHL is stands
 for device read write header size. thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. I am new in stack overflow. I messed the things little bit. but I was eager to solve my problem. but I will be stuck with protocols of stack overflow in future. thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

> but I want to mention that here in my code DEVRD = 0000 0100 (i.e. decimal 4 or interrupt 04h which is for overflow) and DRDWRHL = 0001 0110 (i.e. decimal 22 or interrupt 16h which is for keyboard input). here i am confused that why we will we put here (0000 0100 SHL 8) in CH and (0001 0110) in CL. what is it means that we are trying to put two interrupt types (04h for overflow and 16h for keyboard input) into counter register CX. what is counter register CX is doing here.

The word sized `CX` register is used here conveniently to write shorter code.
The instruction

```
MOV CX,(DEVRD SHL 8) OR DRDWRHL
```

is equivalent to

```
MOV CL, DRDWRHL
MOV CH, DEVRD
```

The `CX` version requires 3 bytes, the `CL` `CH` version requires 4 bytes.
Because this technique is repeated many times, a considerable savings is achieved.

> what is it means that we are trying to put two interrupt types (04h for overflow and 16h for keyboard input) into counter register CX

This is not the case. If you look further down the program you'll see that `CL` gets stored in a variable *IOCALL.REQLEN*. A name that clearly suggests a length.
Further proof that `CL` is used in a temporary fashion comes from the fact that soon after it gets overwritten by whatever value is in `AH` (either 86h or 87h).